# Testing file uploading

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rspec

I have simple CSV uploading:

Model:

```
def import_links(file)
  CSV.foreach(file.path) do |row|
    links.create(Hash[%w(url text description).zip row])
  end 
end
```

Form:

```
<%= form_tag import_links_board_path(@board), multipart: true do %>
  <%= file_field_tag :file %><br/>
  <%= submit_tag "Import" %>
<% end %>
```

Controller:

```
def import_links
  @board = Board.find(params[:id])
  @board.import_links(params[:file])
  redirect_to @board
end
```

I'd like to test this model's #import_links method, so probably would like to have something like :

```
before :each do
  @file = ...
end
```

Unfortunately, I don't have idea how generate this file (manually, or even better using FactoryGirl).

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0):

I have used this helper for integrations tests in rspec:

```
module PathHelpers
  def file_path(name)
    File.join("spec", "support", "files", name)
  end
end

RSpec.configuration.include PathHelpers
```

Then, put your test files in the `spec/support/files` and you can use it inside your tests:

```
scenario "create new estimate" do
  visit new_estimate_path

  fill_in 'Title', with: 'Cool estimate'
  attach_file 'CSV', file_path('estimate_items.csv')

  expect { click_button "Create estimate" }.to change(Estimate, :count).by(1)
end
```

For FactoryGirl factories, I have something like this:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :estimate_upload do
    estimate
    excel File.open(File.join(Rails.root, 'spec', 'support', 'files', 'estimate_items.csv'))
  end
end
```

Hope that everything is clear!

Comment: It's not exactly what I need. I think I solved it by moving test file to `spec/fixtures` and then `@file = fixture_file_upload '/links.txt', 'text/plain'` in `before :each` block.

Comment: Just tested this File.open and it works fine as well. Don't know which way is better.